# 2nd elseif "Header Location" statement, not redirecting (no error)

Tags: php, header

My 2nd elseif "Header Location" statement is not redirecting (no error).

Warning: I am a complete beginner at php so please only constructive criticism please.

My PHP code:

```
<?php
$myusername = $_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword = $_POST['mypassword'];
$session = "0";
$db = mysql_connect("X.HOST.X", "User_name", "Password");
mysql_select_db("User_name", $db);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE usr = '$myusername'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ob_start();
    echo $row["usr"];
    $usr = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();
    echo $row["regIP"];
    $regIP = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    ob_start();
    echo $row["pass"];
    $pass = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();
    echo $usr . $regIP . $pass;
    $salted_DataBase = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();
    echo $myusername . $regIP . $mypassword;
    $salted_User = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $session = "0";
    if ($salted_User == $salted_DataBase) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO online (id, usr, online, dt) VALUES( '', '$myusername.IN', '1', NOW() )");
        header("location:Secured_Page.php");
    } elseif ($session = "0") {
        header("location:google.com");
    }
}
?>
```

What strikes me as odd is that the fist "Header Location" part of the if else statement works properly and will redirect you to the proper location. This issue is killing me because all of my log error folders are empty and I have no error out put on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vivek is right. Your if statement isn't right.

But another thing is that you should use mysqli_* functions instead of mysql_* functions. This is because mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be removed in the future. mysqli_* functions are an improved version of the mysql_* functions... 
[PHP.net page about mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Also, when your in your while statement, you use `ob_*` to get and set variables. That can be done much more simple:

This code:

```
    ob_start();
    echo $row["usr"];
    $usr = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();
    echo $row["regIP"];
    $regIP = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
```

Will then be this code:

```
    $usr = $row["usr"];
    $regIP = $row["regIP"];
```

**UPDATE 1:**
Here's you're code with some improvements. Hope that it works:

```
<?php
$myusername = $_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword = $_POST['mypassword'];
$session = 0;

$db = @new mysqli("X.HOST.X", "User_name", "Password", "User_name( db select here )");
// Works as of PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
if ($mysqli -> connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli -> connect_error);
}

if ($result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM members WHERE usr = '$myusername'")) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $usr = $row["usr"];
        $regIP = $row["regIP"];
        $pass = $row["pass"];
        $salted_DataBase = $usr . $regIP . $pass;
        $salted_User = $myusername . $regIP . $mypassword;

        if ($salted_User == $salted_DataBase) {
            mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO online (id, usr, online, dt) VALUES( '', '$myusername', '1', NOW() )");
            header("Location: Secured_Page.php");
        } elseif ($session == 0) {
            header("Location: http://www.google.com");
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "No User found with the given name";
}
?>
```

I've updated your code to `mysqli_*` functions, made an integer of the `session` variable ( better fault control ), removed the `ob_*` functions, fixed the elseif statement ( added an `=` ) and fixed the header link ( without `http://www.` you will have the chance that it will search the page on the original domain where you are. So it's better to always use `http://www.` when your redirecting to an different domain ).

Comment: @user2535859, i've updated my answer with the right code. Try that. Hope that it work...

Comment: Dude you are so AWESOME!! Thanks im going to play around with it now, I'll let you know how things work out!!

Comment: @user2535859 Glad i could help. 1 more thing to think about is `SQL injection`. But that's for later. First understand the basics ;)

Comment: Ok... So after I swapped your code for mine I am still in the same situation. Where the first "header Location" will redirect but the second "header Location" is still not working. No error message??? Thanks a million for updating my code!!! Would just love to get this issue resolved... By the way I host with godaddy, dont know if this makes a difference.

Comment: Found some material on-line about godaddy and PHP Header Errors On Server Side Redirects "php output buffer error".

Comment: I also posted this issue on godaddys support forum, so if they are able to resolve this issue I will update you all as soon as possible. Thanks a million for all of your great help so fare =B

Comment: @user2535859, is this all the code??? also turn on error reporting ( [Error Reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Here is my updated code, it is a work around but I am still able to achieve the same result.

Comment: Sorry.... I tried to upload my code earlier and this forum was not allowing me to post for one reason or another. Stackoverflow.com is new to me so I'm still getting use to everything. So basically I took out the second "header Location redirect" and inserted this code at the end of my php script.

Comment: if ($salted_User == $salted_DataBase) {
            mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO online (id, usr, online, dt) VALUES( '', '$myusername', '1', NOW() )");
            header("Location: Secured_Page.php");
        }}}
?>
<html>
<title>!!PASSWORD/USERNAME!!</title> 
<style type="text/css" >
body
{
background-image:url('padlock.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:center;
} 
</style> 
<body>
<center>
<b>WRONG USERNAME AND OR PASSWORD</b>
</center>
</body>
<style>
</style>

Comment: Here is the path to my login page .. so that you can get a better idea of whats going on. URL: http://pullussolutions.com/Backup/Login/LoginForm.php                                                                                                                           Temp Username/Password: MickyMouse/hhHH66^^

Comment: @Philcinbox, i think it has something to do with the security check now. Can you make an dump of the DB and email that in an zip with all the www page's? In that way i've got an great overvieuw. email: `difrncestick@gmail.com`

Comment: Yeah sure.. Let me get it together tonight and I'll send it on over. Thanks again.

Comment: @Philcinbox, alright, hope that that means that you succedded. Hope that you will become a master at programming. If you need any futher help, just post it here on Stackoverflow and where willing to help :D

Answer (score 1):

You are using assignment operator. Change this:-

```
elseif ($session = "0")
```

to

```
elseif ($session == "0")
```

Comment: I figured it out... my second elseif statement had only 1 "=" sign instead of 2. Thanks anyways =B

Comment: @user2535859, That's what Vivek said. If your happy with his help, remember to upvote and tick the mark under the vote part to accept his answer as the best real answer...

Comment: I also posted this issue on godaddys support forum, so if they are able to resolve this issue I will update you all as soon as possible. Thanks a million for all of your great help so fare =B